# How to get top values based on last_col() and then arrange in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to get `top 20` countries that have the most number of covid cases by `latest date`. Data is in `wide format` and `latest date` is the `last column`.

```
install.packages("covid19.analytics")

library(tidyverse)
library(covid19.analytics)

df <- covid19.data("ts-confirmed")
head(df)

############ output ############

Province.State Country.Region Lat Long 2020-01-22 2020-01-23
<chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>

Argentina   -38.41610   -63.61670   0   0   
Bangladesh  23.68500    90.35630    0   0   
Brazil  -14.23500   -51.92530   0   0   
Chile   -35.67510   -71.54300   0   0   
Colombia    4.57090 -74.29730   0   0   
France  46.22760    2.21370 0   0   
Germany 51.16569    10.45153    0   0   
India   20.59368    78.96288    0   0
```

I am taking `top 20` from data frame by applying it on `last_col()` which is the latest date as shown in code below and that works well.

**Issue:** But when I pipe this to arrange for desc order then it gives me an error.

`arrange()` part in below code is not working and I am not sure why it's giving me an error as I am supplying `.` data frame to it and arranging on basis of `last_col()`.

```
  top_n(df, n =20, wt = df %>% select(last_col())) %>%
    arrange(., . %>% select(last_col()))
```

(in code havn't used `desc` as it was giving an error anyways but will use once it works).

It's strange that `top_n` doesn't sorts on its own by default because top n means from the top so ideally it should have sort in descending on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `arrange`, we can use `across` instead of subsetting with `select` as `arrange` is looking for either the unquoted column name instead of the full column values

```
library(dplyr)
library(covid19.analytics)
top_n(df, n =20, wt = df %>%
           select(last_col())) %>%
    arrange(across(last_col()))
```

---

It can be also written as

```
top_n(df, n = 20, wt = !! rlang::sym(names(df)[ncol(df)])) %>% 
        arrange(across(last_col()))
```

---

NOTE: If we don't want to repeat the 'df', we could use `.`, but `.` is mostly used when we have a chain (`%>%`) to specify the data from the lhs of `%>%`.  Another option is `cur_data`

```
top_n(df, n =20, wt = cur_data() %>% 
          select(last_col())) %>%
 nrow
#[1] 20
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for showing both the solutions and it worked. I think I will stick with across as `rlang` confuses me a alot. Its not letting me accept the answer before certain time limit, will do as soon as it let me do. Thanks again !!

Comment: @ViSa Based on my dplyr version, it returns 20 rows `top_n(df, n =20, wt = df %>%
           select(last_col())) %>% nrow#
[1] 20`

Comment: @ViSa the difference is that you are usingn `.` instead of `df`.  `.` is used when you have are chaining with `%>%`

Comment: yes that was working. It was my bad. I tried replacing `df` with `.` and got more rows for `top_n(df, n =20, wt = . %>% select(last_col()))`. Your solution worked !!

Comment: @ViSa you could use `cur_data` as well

Comment: ok, I didn't know about `cur_data`, will surely try that as well. Thanks for helping me :)